# Is there a way to access appSettings.json globally?

Tags: c#, configuration, console-application, connection-string, dbcontext

I have a C# console app, and I'm defining an IConfiguration object as follows inside of Program.cs:

```
var myConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{myEnvironment}.json", true, true)
            .Build();
```

... and I can reference settings from within that same Program.cs file like this:

```
var mySetting = myConfig.GetValue<string>("Section:SettingName");
```

However, I'm wondering what would be the way to access that same myConfig object from other files in my application?  For instance, myConfig contains a connection string, but I don't actually make use of the connection string until a few layers deeper (inside of myService > myRepository > myDbContext).  What is a best practice to read that connection string from inside of myRepository or myDbContext?  Obviously, I can pass the connection string as a parameter from Program.cs and myService, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Are you looking for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: You could just write the json to file

Answer (score 2):

You can use the build-in DI (Dependency Injection), which also works for .NET C# Console Applications as already mentioned here

[How to use Dependency Injection in .Net core Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369845/how-to-use-dependency-injection-in-net-core-console-application)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `IConfiguration` to your constructor. You can use `Bind` calls to create objects from it, or just read it like a dictionary.